# SQL query to calculate the users with highest success rate of answering questions

Tags: mysql, sql

I am stuck trying to come up with an sql query that will calculate the top five users which have the highest success rate of questions answered. I have a query that retrieves the top five users who answered the most questions, doesn't matter if answer is correct

```
SELECT b.user_id, 
   Count(1) AS answers, 
   username
FROM   score a 
   JOIN processedquestion b 
     ON a.attempt_id = b.attempt_id 
   JOIN users c 
     ON b.user_id = c.user_id 
WHERE  selected_answer IS NOT NULL 
GROUP  BY user_id 
ORDER  BY Count(1) DESC 
LIMIT  5
```

and I have a query that has the top five users with the most correct answers

```
SELECT b.user_id, 
   Count(1) AS correct_answers, 
   username 
FROM   score a 
   JOIN processedquestion b 
     ON a.attempt_id = b.attempt_id 
   JOIN users c 
     ON b.user_id = c.user_id 
WHERE  selected_answer = correct_answer 
GROUP  BY user_id 
ORDER  BY Count(1) DESC 
LIMIT  5
```

What I am trying to do is have a query that will now return the top five users by the success rate percentage of all their answers. So if a user has only answered one question and it is correct they will be returned in the query with having 100% success rate. The tables that I am working with are

```
ProcessedQuestions(attempt_id, user_id, question_id, attempt_datetime)
Score(score_id, attempt_id, correct_answer, selected_answer)
Users(user_id, first_name, last_name)
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation.  In MySQL, this is pretty easy using `avg()`:

```
SELECT b.user_id, username, count(*) as answers,
       avg(selected_answer = correct_answer) as p_correct
FROM score a JOIN
     processedquestion b 
     ON a.attempt_id = b.attempt_id JOIN
     users c 
     ON b.user_id = c.user_id 
WHERE selected_answer IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY user_id 
ORDER BY p_correct DESC
LIMIT 5;
```